# How can I see a list of my reviews in iPad Apple Store?

Tags: ipad, apple-store

I want to see a list of my rewiews so I can keep track of apps I have reviewed and perhaps share them to my friends. So, how can I preview my reviews, i.e. the feedback, feature-request and such things for developers to get better, in iPad Apple Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the desktop iTunes application:

> - Sign in to the iTunes Store.
> - From the Store menu, chose View My Account.
> - In the Settings section, click Manage next to "Reviews and Ratings."

from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5024

Comment: Shortly, you need to have iTunes ie OSx or Windows to preview your previews. Haven't found any other way so *ix -users without Windows or OSx cannot preview things.